# How do i draw a circle in the middle of a Form and how do i find the circle center?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int x1, x2, wid = 100;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            x1 = this.Width / 2 ;
            x2 = this.Height / 2 ;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {


            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, x1,x2, wid, wid);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to draw a simple circle in the middle of the form and then later on i want to draw lines coming out from the circle center. How can i do it ?

Comment: *(`x1`, `x2`)* should be the circle center.

Comment: This appears to be a homework question. Have you tried to solve this problem and, if so, what is your specific problem with the implementation?

Comment: @oldrinb, you are wrong: If you use (x1, x2), then you will be off-center every time! You should instead construct a rectangle, use the extension methods from here (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/403031/Extension-methods-for-finding-centers-of-a-rectang) to get the center point of the rectangle, and then use the rectangle to construct the ellipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the properties `this.Width` and `this.Height` are the same as `this.Bounds` which describes itself as:

> Gets or sets the size and location of the control including its
>   non-client elements, on pixels, relative to the parent control

this means you'd need to adjust for the thickness of the borders and the title bar. Using `this.ClientRectangle` avoids that whole issue.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int circleDiameter  = 100;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

     private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Point CenterPoint = new Point()
        {
            X = this.ClientRectangle.Width/2,
            Y = this.ClientRectangle.Height/2
        };
        Point topLeft = new Point()
        {
            X=(this.ClientRectangle.Width - circleDiameter) / 2,
            Y=(this.ClientRectangle.Height - circleDiameter) / 2
        };
        Point topRight = new Point()
        {
            X=(this.ClientRectangle.Width + circleDiameter) / 2,
            Y=(this.ClientRectangle.Height - circleDiameter) / 2
        };
        Point bottomLeft = new Point()
        {
            X=(this.ClientRectangle.Width - circleDiameter) / 2,
            Y=(this.ClientRectangle.Height + circleDiameter) / 2
        };
        Point bottomRight = new Point()
        {
            X=(this.ClientRectangle.Width + circleDiameter) / 2,
            Y=(this.ClientRectangle.Height + circleDiameter) / 2
        };

         e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, topLeft.X, topLeft.Y, circleDiameter, circleDiameter);
         e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, CenterPoint, topLeft);
         e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, CenterPoint, topRight);
         e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, CenterPoint, bottomLeft);
         e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, CenterPoint, bottomRight);
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
    }

}
```

Comment: Brad thats great for the drawing a circle or a square in the middle of the Form. Now i need to find how to calculate and draw a line or a pixle from the circle then when its a square and then when its a rectangle center.

Comment: I think there's enough in there for you to play with and see how to draw other lines. to make the lines go from the center of a circle to its edges you'll have to use some trig functions which are in the `System.Math` library. Either use SOH CAH TOA or Pythagorean. either one will get your rays to the edge of the circle

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, is this what you want to do?

```
        const int circleRadius = 150;
        const int circleDiameter = circleRadius * 2;

        const double angleOfLineInDegrees = 65;
        const double angleOfLineInRadians = (angleOfLineInDegrees / 180) * Math.PI;

        // Center of the form
        var cirleCenter = new PointF(((float)Width / 2), ((float)Height / 2));

        // Ellipses draw like a rectangle. 
        // So just start at the center 
        // subtract by the radius along x and y axis
        // make the width and height the diameter.
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, cirleCenter.X - circleRadius, cirleCenter.Y - circleRadius, circleDiameter, circleDiameter);

        // This line is using trig to convert the angle into a usable vector
        var lineVector = new PointF((float)Math.Cos(angleOfLineInRadians) * circleRadius, (float)Math.Sin(angleOfLineInRadians) * circleRadius);

        var lineEndPoint = new PointF(cirleCenter.X + lineVector.X, cirleCenter.Y + lineVector.Y);

        // Draw the line starting at 
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, cirleCenter, lineEndPoint);
```