# how to get Coordinates in a circle

Tags: c#

i want to know how to

make a circle from a point and how to check if an account is inside this circle .

i get an idea but i don't know if it's good i thought that i can make a circle from a center point  and from the account Coordinates i get the distance from it to the center of the circle and see if the distance is smaller than the Radius of the circle ........

but can i know how i can get some coordinates in this circle which its distance between it and the center equals the radius

Comment: This sounds more suitable for http://mathoverflow.net/. Can you please rephrase "but can i know how i can get some coordinates in this circle which its distance between it and the center equals the radius"?

Comment: Read here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198764/how-to-know-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle

Comment: This question is unclear (though regardless almost certainly a duplicate of an existing question, assuming it's on-topic at all). Do you want to be able to test a point to see if it's inside a circle, or do you want to be able to compute the points that are _on_ the circle (i.e. the distance from the point to the center _"equals the radius"_, as you wrote)? Please do some research so we can tell exactly which question yours is a duplicate of.

Comment: What is a circle in your application? A geaometric object? A numer of colored pixels?? And what is an _account_ that could be in it???

Answer (score 0):

I think that it has been answered but since you did not provide much details (use WinForms or other frameworks) I will provide you with links: 
draw a circle in WF [C# Drawing circles in a panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730828/c-sharp-drawing-circles-in-a-panel) 
determine if coordinates within a circle https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198764/how-to-know-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle 
[How do i draw a circle in the middle of a Form and how do i find the circle center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344230/how-do-i-draw-a-circle-in-the-middle-of-a-form-and-how-do-i-find-the-circle-cent)